# Search results from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to tell ElasticSearch to include in results the keywords for which the "document" was found?

For example, I'm adding these documents to ES:

```
{
    "text": "C# is the best language"
}
{
    "text": "Javascript is the worst language"
}
```

Then I query them:

```
{
    "query": { "match": { "text": "C# javascript" } }
}
```

Can ES tell me that the 1st document was found by "C#" keyword and the second - by "javascript" keyword ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) to achieve this

**Ingest documents**

```
POST test_pavel/_doc
{
    "text": "C# is the best language"
}

POST test_pavel/_doc
{
    "text": "Javascript is the worst language"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_pavel/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "c# javascript"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931471,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_pavel",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RNCc_XcB46EpgstaSy19",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "C# is the best language"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "text" : [
            "<em>C</em># is the best language"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_pavel",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RdCc_XcB46EpgstaUC34",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "Javascript is the worst language"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "text" : [
            "<em>Javascript</em> is the worst language"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```